# Epplus excel conditional formatting databar max value

Tags: c#, excel, conditional-formatting, epplus, epplus-4

I'm creating an excel file with epplus, and I'm trying to add a databar with the following code:

```
var bar = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1].ConditionalFormatting.AddDatabar(new ExcelAddress("I4:I56"), System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
            bar.HighValue.Type = eExcelConditionalFormattingValueObjectType.Num;
            bar.LowValue.Type = eExcelConditionalFormattingValueObjectType.Num;
            bar.HighValue.Value = 600;
            bar.LowValue.Value = 0;
```

However, cells with the value 600 do not fully fill. They look like this:

[image]

When I expect it to look like this, which is how it comes out if you set it to 600 within excel:
[image]

I have tried adding the xml manually as suggested in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33568285/1308743 and the same issue persists.

Comment: Something is different in the XLSX output, but I don't know what. What I would do: make a very simple XLSX file and diff the files inside the ZIP package to see what's different. If EPPlus is doing something odd, then propose a change to the code.

Comment: @DanWilson Thanks for the suggestion Dan. I made a simple example from code and manually that has the difference, but I'm not sure how to go about doing a file diff since opening up the xlsx in a text editor shows a bunch unreadable characters.

Comment: Rename the XLSX to ZIP and extract the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33568285/3286163) in the link you provided does work for me, you might just need to update the cell reference in `xm:sqref` to point to your I4:I56 address instead, which I believe is why it does not work for you.

To explain the visual issue, the `dataBar` that EPPlus generates in the xml is missing the `minLength` and `maxLength` attributes. These attributes define the fixed width percentage that the data bar fills. By [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.databar?view=openxml-2.8.1), the min length is 10% and max length is 90%.

If you don't care about removing the gradient, you can directly add the `minLength` and `maxLength` without creating the extension list like in the linked answer if you want a simpler solution:

```
// All the code below goes after your code that creates the data bar
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

// Create namespace manager using default uri to be able to select nodes.
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(ws.WorksheetXml.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("d", ws.WorksheetXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

// Get all the dataBar elements and set the missing min and max length attributes.
var dataBarElements = ws.WorksheetXml.SelectNodes("//d:dataBar", ns);
foreach (XmlElement dataBarElement in dataBarElements)
{
    dataBarElement.SetAttribute("minLength", "0");
    dataBarElement.SetAttribute("maxLength", "100");
}
```

The above applies it to all data bars. If you want to only apply it to the one databar like for I4:I56, change the selection to:

```
var dataBarElement = (XmlElement)ws.WorksheetXml.SelectSingleNode("//d:conditionalFormatting[@sqref='I4:I56']//d:dataBar", ns);
dataBarElement.SetAttribute("minLength", "0");
dataBarElement.SetAttribute("maxLength", "100");
```

If you need to turn off the gradient, you will need to use the answer in your link because the `gradient` attribute doesn't seem to be supported on `dataBar` elements not in an extension list.

I also suggest using the [Open XML SDK Productivity Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=30425) to view/compare the xml in Excel documents.